# REGEX to target all text between two words including the words

Tags: regex, wordpress, str-replace

I have a WordPress function which I would like a part of the intercept to be removed.
Right now the bellow code works 100% only problem is the text isn't static so I need to make a range for it to work on all pots.

This is the code bellow:

```
    function trim_excerpt($text)
{
    return str_replace('Samurai Swords, Ninja Napkins, Samurai Dishes, Art Plates:,', ' ', $text);
}
add_filter('get_the_excerpt', 'trim_excerpt');
```

I tried to make a regex to capture all the text Starting from Samurai Swords, until Plates: but I couldn't as I do not know regEx.

(The only standard words will be the Samurai Swords and Art Plates, all the rest can change. That is why I have the word range Samurai Swords -> Plates)

Any help possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the below regex to capture all the text starting from `Samurai Swords` to `Art Plates:`. `[\S\s]*?`  matches any  space or non-space characters zero or more times(non-greedy).

```
(Samurai\s*Swords[\S\s]*?Art\s*Plates:)
```

Comment: It's not really neccessary to specify the .* at the beginning and end, is it? As the regex should match it anyways

Comment: Also the OP didn't mention anything about "non-static" white-spaces. Wouldn't (Samura Swords.*Art Plates) be more accurate?

Comment: Thank you Avinash, would it pickup also the : at the end of " Arts Plates: "?

@pikausp The text could change as well as the white space since the words are generated automatically based on the products.

Comment: @JackStanson So for example `Samurai       Swords...some text..Art     Plates` should be matched as well?

Comment: It works perfect, thank you very much.
@pikausp I meant in case it was [code] Samurari Swords.. Some     text text      Text text Art Plates: [/code] 
Just tested and it works even for the above example. Again thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) here instead.

```
$text = preg_replace('/Samurai\s*Swords.*?Art\s*Plates:/s', '', $text);
```

This will match everything from "Samurai" to "Plates:" and replace it with an empty value.